# Cross context joins in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, join

This is how I made a cross context join.

What do you think?

How would you do this better?

```
using (var context = ContextFactory.Create())
{
    var users =  await context
                         .Users.AsNoTracking()
                         .OrderBy(user => user.DisplayName)
                         .Where(user => user.AccountName.Contains(query))
                         .Select(user => new UserProfileDTO
                         {
                             Id = user.Id,
                             DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                         })
                         .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var entity = await context.UserInfos.FindAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (entity != null)
            user.HasPicture = entity.HasPicture == true ? true : false;
    }

    return users;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by cross-context? I can see only one context there.

Comment: @t3chb0t context.Users and context.UserInfos ?

Comment: Aren't those tables?

Comment: oh, yes. So it isn't cross context ?

Comment: cross context would be between two databases - this is just a normal join between two tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results with a single query like this one:

```
var result = await
    (from u in context.Users
     join ui in context.UserInfos on u.Id equals ui.UserId
     where u.AccountName.Contains(query) && ui.HasPicture
     select new UserProfileDTO
     {
         Id = u.Id,
         DisplayName = u.DisplayName,
     }
    ).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This would select all users with a picture in their user-info.

I assumed the `UserInfo` table has a foreign-key `UserId` that you can use for joining both tables.

---

This by the way

> ```
> user.HasPicture = entity.HasPicture == true ? true : false;
> ```

is the same as:

```
user.HasPicture = entity.HasPicture;
```

Comment: and how would you use await in this case?

Comment: @SGN same as you did. you wrap it with `()` and add the `.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)` at the end and `async` in front of the query - I added it to the answer.